# Получить результат из метода

Tags: java

Заранее прошу прощения вопрос простой, я новичок в программирование есть код как из него получит Sting hexChars   в другом методе.

```
 private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Comment: `String chars = bytesToHex(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, метод `bytesToHex` работает правильно. Чтобы получить из него то, что он возвращает, сохраните это в переменную в своем методе.

```
 String hexCodeStr = bytesToHex(str.getBytes());
```

где `str` это строка, которую надо преобразовать.